# how to make animation for popup window in android

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

I hava a popup window in my application, its appears when some button clicked
I want to set fade in animation to this window,
I put the xml file in "res/anim" folder and set the animation style for the popup window but the animation does not work?
here is my code:

myanim.xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" 
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
        android:duration="4000"
        android:repeatCount="1"/>
</set>
```

===============================================

Create the popup window

```
private PopupWindow showOptions(Context mcon){
    try{ 
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mcon.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.options_layout,null);
        layout.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.myanim));
        PopupWindow optionspu = new PopupWindow(layout, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        
        optionspu.setFocusable(true);
        optionspu.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
        optionspu.update(0, 0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int)(hei/5));
        optionspu.setAnimationStyle(R.anim.myanim);
        return optionspu;
    }
    catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();
    return null;}
}
```

=================================================
onClick method... (optionsPopup is global variable of type PopupWindow)

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
               switch (v.getId()) { 
        case R.id.options:
                optionsPopup=showOptions(this);
            break;  
}
```

Answer (score 123):

I think the problem is you have provided only one set of animation style. But actually a `PopupWindow` requires two animations. One will be used by it when window is shown and other one to hide the window.

This is how you should do it,

1) Create Two Different set of animations.

say, **popup_show.xml** and **popup_hide.xml** and add it to your **anim** folder which you have to create inside **res** folder.

2) Now inside **values** folder create a xml called **styles.xml** and add these animations to it like this,

```
<style name="Animation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/popup_show</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/popup_hide</item>
</style>
```

3) Now set this style to your `PopupWindow` animation,

```
 popup.setAnimationStyle(R.style.Animation);
```

Now it automatically detects window enter and exit and provides with the required animation.

Comment: This has to set before showaslocation method call surely. But somehow The popup is opening multiple times whenever I click the button, any clues why multiple times?

Comment: I managed to get rid of the double animation by removing android:repeatCount="1" from the animation

Answer (score 17):

i am using a popup animation with this code:

```
// Creating the PopupWindow
       layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)     getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

       inflatedLayoutView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.packages_popup,null);
     inflatedLayoutView.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.animator.popupanim)


    popup_l = new PopupWindow(inflatedLayoutView);

   popup_l.setWidth(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   popup_l.setHeight(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);     
   popup_l.setFocusable(true);
   // Clear the default translucent background
   popup_l.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());       

   popup_l.showAtLocation(parent, Gravity.CENTER, 0 , 0);   

   popup_l.setOutsideTouchable(false);
```

located in /res/animator/popupanim.xml
(popupanim.xml)
  the animation code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" 
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
        android:duration="500"
        android:repeatCount="0"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 13):

The PopupWindow custom layout is more convenient, and the display position is freedom there is not any restricted.
Use Below code and enjoy animation.
In this animation use bottom slide in and slide out but you can change only slide in/out animation and animate any where in your app and one thing more according to your animation, you must to change your  Gravity ->> BOTTOM, TOP etc.

anim resource folder:

1.slide_in_bottom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false"
    >

  <translate
      android:duration="@integer/dialogplus_animation_default_duration"
      android:fromXDelta="0%"
      android:fromYDelta="100%"
      android:toXDelta="0%"
      android:toYDelta="0%"
      />
</set>
```

2.slide_out_bottom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false"
    >

  <translate
      android:duration="@integer/dialogplus_animation_default_duration"
      android:fromXDelta="0%"
      android:fromYDelta="0%"
      android:toXDelta="0%"
      android:toYDelta="100%"
      />
</set>
```

Style:

```
<style name="popup_window_animation">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_bottom</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_bottom</item>
    </style>
```

Method:

```
 private PopupWindow showOptions(Context mcon){
        try{
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mcon.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_option_documents_type,null);
            PopupWindow optionspu = new PopupWindow(layout, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            optionspu.setAnimationStyle(R.style.popup_window_animation);
            optionspu.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
            optionspu.setFocusable(true);
            optionspu.setOutsideTouchable(true);
            optionspu.update(0, 0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            optionspu.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);

            return optionspu;
        }
        catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();
            return null;}
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

This might be a bit late but the reason why the animation did not show is because you are showing the popupwindow before you set up your animation.

```
optionspu.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
optionspu.setAnimationStyle(R.anim.myanim);
```

Reverse the two lines and you will see the animation:

```
optionspu.setAnimationStyle(R.anim.myanim);
optionspu.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to simon's answer, If you don't want to create custom style with custom animation resource, then you can try some default style from `android.R.style` class.

```
popupWindow.animationStyle = android.R.style.Animation_Toast
popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 500)
```