# Having issue with Popup window

Tags: android, kotlin, popupwindow

I am trying to set Popup window similar to the old Facebook comment section.

Rounded corner dialog box but I am facing a problem with `size of dialog box` and `showatlocation` of the Dialog box.

When I try this code on different mobile:

```
        val display = windowManager.defaultDisplay
        val size = Point()
        display.getSize(size)
        val popupWindow = PopupWindow(customView, size.x-30, size.y-300, true)
        popupWindow.showAtLocation(linearLayout1, Gravity.CENTER, -3, 100)
        popupWindow.setAnimationStyle(R.style.PopupAnimation)
```

Xml File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_bg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10px">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/popup_rcv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/new_comment_et"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Please enter Comment" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/comment_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Submit" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

//Animation from [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50582115/10182897)

**Output On Oneplus 6T:**
[image: One plus]

In one plus my animation also disable when I change .showAtLocation to other numbers

**Output on Lenovo K8 Note:**

[image: K8 Note]

In K8 note Location of Popup change if I change to another value.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Why not just use dialog instead it will give your desired affect unless you want the animation.This is way simpler way to prompt user for feedback. This way you don't have to worry about where it will show up plus you can add custom styles to the dialog https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351330/what-is-the-difference-between-popupwindow-and-dialog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like these 2 phones have different screen resolutions. So you have to use DP instead of pixels. Check this [post](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#kotlin)

**Popup size**.
Firstly you have to convert dialog size to pixels.
These are random values and they are hardcoded, but you can take them from resources or harcode too.

```
val popUpWidthDp = 200
val popUpHeightDp = 100

val popUpWidthPx = convertDpToPx(popUpWidthDp)
val popUpHeightPx = convertDpToPx(popUpHeightDp)

val popupWindow = PopupWindow(customView, popUpWidthPx, popUpHeightPx, true)
```

**Popup position**. Firstly you need to convert dp to px and then you can calculate popup position related to screen size.

```
val popUpLeftSideMarginDp = 50
val popUpTopMarginDp = 100

val popUpXPoint = convertDpToPx(popUpLeftSideMarginDp)
val popUpYPoint = convertDpToPx(popUpTopMarginDp)

popupWindow.showAtLocation(linearLayout1, Gravity.CENTER, popUpXPoint, popUpYPoint)
```

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19953871/4410330) to understand how to convert dp into pixels and vise versa.

If popup should have size and position related to screen size then you have to change these values:

- popUpHeightPx, popUpWidthPx  - popup size
- popUpXPoint, popUpYPoint - popup position

Let me know if you need detailed explanation.

Comment: where i need to change pixel to dp means i am not using pixels anywhere not even in my xml file so can you provide more information. Sorry i am new to android designing

Comment: there was animation of slider in popup but it removed after i put those values -3 and 100

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: its not working it says java.lang.Float cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

Comment: I thought you are using Kotlin. Where exactly do you have exception? You need to cast Float to Double explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Create PopupWindow as:

```
popupWindow= new PopupWindow(
                        customView,
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                );
```

And set its location as:

```
popupWindow.showAtLocation(linearLayout1, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)
```

And add customView top margin 10dp or 5dp in xml

Comment: sir i am having issue with popup location and animation if i chnage showatlocation to 0, 0 then in oneplus it shows properly but when i use that values in k8 note then it gives issue and if i use -3, 100 then it works perfect in both but animation of dialog box does not show

Comment: Hi Ashish, have u tried to set height and width parameter as "LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT"

Comment: does it show same height as oneplus image cause i need dialog box of that size

Comment: can u please add xml code of your "customView", so I can help u more

Comment: can u add actual image of "Output on Lenovo K8 Note" when location set to 0,0

Comment: which layoutparams i use there are lot of params

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187982/discussion-between-zumbarlal-saindane-and-ashish).

Answer (score 0):

Try with below solution : its in Java but you can convert it in Kotlin

```
PopupWindow popupWin = new PopupWindow(mContext);

// Measure layout here, then we can get measureHeight.
layout.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
popupWin .setWidth(layout.getMeasuredWidth()); 
popupWin .setHeight(layout.getMeasuredHeight()); //you can pass height as you want.
popupWin .setContentView(layout);
popupWin .showAsDropDown(anchorView,0 ,0, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY);
```

Here `anchorView` is a view in where we want to open `PopupWindow` in as dropdown.

[PopupWindow](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/android.widget.PopupWindow/showAsDropDown)

Comment: i am looking for comment section similar to instagram but smaller in size but there is issue with dialog box. so does anchorView help me ?

Comment: you can try with it to give height and anchorView .

Comment: can you help me with DialogBox or popupwindow cause having issue in multiple section

Comment: Please go through with link added in my answer.

Comment: i tried with your link but there is no solution for my question cause it sticks to screen bottom and animation for exit also disappear

Answer (score 0):

I think you would like to convert the pixels into dp, rather then dp into pixels, in order to fit different resolutions of screens. More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/what-is-the-difference-between-px-dip-dp-and-sp).

This is [how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19953871/8344913) to convert pixels to dp.