# How to set animations for popup menu?

Tags: android

I want to change animations for popup menu.

I have two xml file related to animation action information in `res/anim`.

And I tried to do it but it did not work. Do I use PopupWindow?

`styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
     ...
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/PopupMenuTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenuTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
     ...
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/AnimationTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="AnimationTheme">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/translate_down</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/translate_up</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247792/how-to-make-animation-for-popup-window-in-android/12436853

Comment: @Rohit5k2 I saw it but the problem is I am using popup menu, not popup window. I can't find `setAnimationStyle` in popup menu.. Anyway thank you.